# Android DataBinding - How to Bind A ViewGroup's Properties

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvm-light, android-databinding

I am developing an Android app in Xamarin.Android(C#). However, i do feel that this question can also be answered by any Java devs as well.

I am new in android development. Anyways, i created a fragment with just a `LinearLayout` and a `TextView` inside it. When i create the background class for it, i don't inherit(on in JAVA's word, `extend`) it from the `Fragment` class but rather from the `LinearLayout` class.

So, the `MyFragment.cs` file starts like this :

```
public class MyFragment : LinearLayout
```

The JAVA equivalent would be

```
public class MyFragment extends LinearLayout
```

(P.S. I have limited knowledge of JAVA and it's sytaxes).

Anyways, all works fine. I have an `Initialize` method(In JAVA, it should be the `Init` method) which inflates the view of the fragment. From the view, it tries to find the `TextView` with the given `Id`.

So, the codes looks like this :

```
public class MyFragment : LinearLayout
{
 Context mContext;
  private void Initialize(Context ctx)
  {
        //Inflating the layout
        mContext = ctx;
        var inflatorService = (LayoutInflater)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View v = inflatorService.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentView, this, false);
        this.AddView(v);
        GoalHeader = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.GoalHeader);
  }
```

All works pretty well this far. I then go on implementing the MVVM pattern, using `MVVMLight` library. I create a `ViewModel` as follows :

```
 public class Vm_MyFragment : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _goaltitle = "";
    public string GoalTitle
    {
        get { return _goaltitle; }
        set { Set(ref _goaltitle, value); }
    }
    public void SetTest()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
            GoalTitle = "Test";
        });
    }
}
```

Still, everything's good. The problem starts when i try to bind the `TextView`'s text property to the `ViewModel`'s `GoalTitle` property, as follows :

```
 private readonly List<Binding> _bindings = new List<Binding>();

 private void Initialize(Context ctx)
    {
        //Inflating the layout
        mContext = ctx;
        var inflatorService = (LayoutInflater)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View v = inflatorService.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentView, this, false);
        this.AddView(v);
        Vm_MyFragmentView viewmodel = new Vm_MyFragmentView();
        GoalHeader = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.GoalHeader);
        _bindings.Add(
            this.SetBinding(
                () => mainViewModel.GoalTitle,
                () => GoalHeader.Text));
    }
```

> Note : `Binding` is from the `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers` namespace.

I add the fragment in my main view(I mean, `MainActivity`'s view) and debug the app. Upon execution, i get the following error :

> Could not activate JNI Handle 0xfff02a68 (key_handle 0x339790a) of Java type 'md55bfae9a06327fa0fdf207b4f768604b1/MyFragment' as managed type 'TestApp.MyFragment'.

Searching google, i realized that i am trying to bind the property before the view is even created(correct me if i'm wrong). The suggestions i found on other SO answers were either to put the code in the `OnCreateView` method or somehow delay the execution of the *binding part's* code.

The first solution didn't work for me as `LinearLayout` aka a `View` doesn't have such a method `OnCreateView` which i can override.

So, how am i supposed to bind the `TextView` to the `ViewModel` then? And also, am i on the right track on treating the fragment as a `LinearLayout` as i am inheriting from it?

Comment: Do you debug the line where the error appears? I think this mistake might be here `View v = inflatorService.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentView, this, false);`

Comment: The error appears on the `_bindings.Add` line.

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with MVVMLIght extension but if you are using a fragment as it is supposed to (ie. in a tablayout) you should inherit from a fragment like this (This is a v4 support fragment):

```
public class CategoryFragment : SupportFragment {
RecyclerView _recyclerView;
private View _view;

public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout._CategoryLayout, container, false);

    // Get our RecyclerView layout:
    _recyclerView = _view.FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.categoryRecyclerView);

    // Instantiate the layout manager
    var linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (Context, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
    _recyclerView.SetLayoutManager (linearLayoutManager);

    // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:
    _adapter = new CategoryAdapter (_categories);
    //Register the item click handler with the adapter:
    _adapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
    // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
    _recyclerView.SetAdapter (_adapter);
    return _view;
}
```

}

Comment: I can do that, however it doesn't address my main problem. Anyways, good job for pointing it out. +1