# Android : Binding Properties Of A Compound View

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, android-databinding

(P.S. I am new to Android development, so yeah, i can use some silly *terms*).

So, have a blank Xamarin.Android(C#) project. I am sure any Java developer can also help me in this case.

Anyways, so i have an `xml` file, inside it there's the `LinearLayout` ViewGroup and it has a nested `TextView`. Looks something like this(By the way, the xml file is named as `custom_View.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout....
       .....
       .....>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/TextView1"
      ...../>
</LinearLayout>
```

The background class that i created for this *custom view* inherits(or `extends` in Java's words) the `LinearLayout` class. Inside it's constructor, i call a method which inflates the view from the `xml` file.

It goes like this :

```
public TestView(Context context) : base(context)
{
    Initialize(context);
}
private void Initialize(Context ctx)
{
    //Inflating the layout
    mContext = ctx;
    var inflatorService = (LayoutInflater)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View v = inflatorService.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_View, this, false);
    this.AddView(v);

    TextView tv = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextView1);
}
```

Now note that i am trying to reference the `TextView` from the xml file in code-behind.

My basic question is, where do i bind it's properties? Like for example, if i want to bind the `Text` property of the `TextView` which method should i put the codes in ? (I know how to bind the properties, but not posting the codes here as they are irrelevant.)

I have gone through other posts on SO, but i can't seem to find which method should i override and bind the properties there? I tried to bind the properties within the `Initialize` method but it throws an error which basically means that i am trying to bind the property before the view is created?

So, which method should i override? Is there any equivalent method to `OnViewCreated` in the `LinearLayout`/`ViewGroup` class?

**EDIT**

[Please read my binding code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898620/android-databinding-how-to-bind-a-viewgroups-properties)

Comment: After you inflated the view, it should be already created and you should be able to edit the text property. Can you show us the code for the binding and the errors? It seems to me that what you've tried should work

Comment: Refer to my this questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898620/android-databinding-how-to-bind-a-viewgroups-properties

It has all the codes.

Comment: You can refer to this link http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/getting-started-with-xamarin-mvvm-light-android-step-by-step/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT, i have been following just that and that's how i got so far. However, it doesn't refer to my situation. My situation is that, i put a compound/custom view inside a fragment. I then put the fragment in an activity. The example in the link suggests to do the bindings in the activity itself. However, i am trying to do the bindings in the code-behind of the custom/compound view. Is this possible?